# Database event trigger by timer

Tags: php, sql

Suppose I have a table with the current users logged in on my website. And if I there isn't any "activity" from one of his/her username in a time interval it would be deleted from the table.

What would be the easiest way to implement this functionality?

Besides using batch files or something like that.

I searched but database triggers can't be timed programmed, at least from what I gathered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would have something like this:

- A table would have a column named something like `last_activity` which stores a timestamp of when the user last visited a page
- You check via a query if a user has been active within a certain amount of time (ex: `WHERE last_activity - current_time < 60` [active in the last minute])

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: why to schedule it?

Comment: because after the period of no activity might mean they have logged off, in which case you need an 'entry point' to run a process....

Comment: nice idea...many thanks for the help...I'll set that present users are those who have done anything in the last 5 mins for example.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: if there is no users on the site - then no one cares about state of activity table ;-) And when someone will enter the site after, for example, 1 hour - all obsolete records will be deleted.

Comment: @ zerkms: talk to the poster. I didn't post the question.